# MAMP on mac with existing mysql server

Tags: mysql, mac, mamp

I am facing some issue in getting MAMP work with existing mysql database on my mac? Sometimes the problem is permission, sometimes it is not able to find the problem or something else.

I will be more specific once I get answers to the following questions

- Can MAMP work with an existing database on Mac. I think it should be?
- Do I have to change the default engine to myisam as of now my default engine in InnoDB?

I have tried these options

- Running start.sh directly, with current user/root
- Changing startMysql run the mysql with sudo command
- Stopping mysql server from System preferences because sometimes I get this error ( in infinite loop)

> InnoDB: using the same InnoDB data or
>   log files. InnoDB: Unable to lock
>   /usr/local/mysql/data/ibdata1, error:
>   35 InnoDB: Check that you do not
>   already have another mysqld process

Can you tell, what may be going wrong here based on this info? If required I will be more specific in stating my problem

Answer (score 1):

It's really in the way MySQL is launched / configured inside MAMP.

I faced the same issue having a second MySQL server compiled on a Mac having its own MySQL server.

I found out a way to launch MySQL without reading any configuration (and particularly the one in /etc/my.cnf) and then to make it use a specific one with proper configuration for socket, port, data directories, etc.

My guess is that this is where your issue is.

;-)